# Gnome controll center online accounts and Thunderbird

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, online-accounts

I'm trying to set up my work-mail (Microsoft Exchange) on my laptop. It didn't work doing it in Thunderbird, so I tried connecting through Online Accounts in Gnome Controll Panel (already using this to connect to my Google Drive, and the standard settings online accounts doesn't support Exchange).

Gnome Controll Center connects without problems, but my account still doesn't pop up in Thunderbird. Same goes for the Gmail. So far only the Google Drive works.

How do I make Thunderbird use the account information from Gnome Controll Center?

Comment: GNOME 3 online accounts integrate with the Evolution mail client, so if you had evolution installed when setting up your online accounts, your gmail account, gmail calendar, etc would appear there.

Comment: Does that mean that it can't integrate with Thunderbird?

Comment: Automatically no. You can manually add your gmail account to thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is not implemented yet. See
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=847989

But it supported by Evolution and Geary.